# How to compare 2 textures in JavaScript / WebGL2?

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures, fragment-shader, webgl2

I am writing a fragment shader for an image processing algorithm. The shader will run multiple times between two framebuffers in a loop (ping-pong). At some point I need to stop the loop when input and output textures are identical.

What I intend to do is the last step of Canny edge detector algorithm, "hysterezis edge tracking". I want to make a real time GPU/WebGL2 version of Canny algorithm and upload it to a web site.

This last step is as follows:
Given a double thresholded image containing "strong" edge pixels (1.0) and "weak" edge pixels (0.5)

- find all chains of weak pixels connected with a strong pixel and mark them "strong"
- keep all "strong" pixels and discard all remaining "weak" ones.

This can be implemented in a fragment shader running multiple times in a loop. The current "weak" pixel is marked "strong" if there is at least one strong pixel in its 8-pixel neighbourhood. At every iteration, we should have more strong pixels and less weak pixels. At the end, only isolated chains of weak pixel should remain. This is the point where the fragment shader becomes a pass-through shader and should be detected to stop the loop.

Update Sept 2019: I uploaded the GPU Canny Edge Detector here http://www.oldrinb.info/dip/canny/ . It works in browsers with WebGL2 support, as well in browsers that support WebGL1 and 'WEBGL_draw_buffers' extension. I'll put also the source code to github shortly.

Comment: By "no output" do you mean (a) the results are exactly the same or do you mean (b) no pixels were actually written, they were all discarded or clipped. For (b) you can maybe use occlusion queries in WebGL2. They tell you how many pixels were drawn. For (a) you could make a shader that given 2 textures compares them and writes 1 pixel with the answer which you read with the CPU ... or combine that with (b) by making it do the comparison and write or don't write that pixel and use occlusion query to check

Comment: I corrected my question because it was wrong. In fact, everytime is something written in the output texture. The moment I need to stop the loop is that one when the input texture is just copied to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. You're asking to compare on the CPU. You can read the contents of a texture by attaching it to a framebuffer and then calling `gl.readPixels`. you can then compare all the pixels. Note: not all texture formats can be attached to a framebuffer but assuming you're using a format that can. You've already attached textures to framebuffers for your ping-ponging so what more did you want?

Like I wrote in the comment on the GPU you can write a shader to compare 2 textures

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  ivec2 size = textureSize(tex1, 0);  // size of mip 0
  float len = 0.0;
  for (int y = 0; y < size.y; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; ++x) {
      vec4 color1 = texelFetch(tex1, ivec2(x, y), 0);
      vec4 color2 = texelFetch(tex2, ivec2(x, y), 0);
      vec4 diff = color1 - color2;
      len = length(diff);
      if (len > 0.0) break;
    }
    if (len > 0.0) break;
  }
  outColor = mix(vec4(0), vec4(1), step(len, 0.0));
}
```

now just draw 1 pixel and read it with readPixels. if it's 0 the textures are the same. If it's not they are different.

The code assumes the textures are the same size but of course if they aren't the same size then we already know they can't be the same.

```js
// make 3 canvaes as sources for textures
const canvases = ['A', 'B', 'B'].map((msg) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 128;
  canvas.height = 128;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.font = '80px monospace';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fillText(msg, 64, 64);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  return canvas;
});

const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
if (!gl) { alert('need webgl2'); }

const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  ivec2 size = textureSize(tex1, 0);  // size of mip 0
  float len = 0.0;
  for (int y = 0; y < size.y; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; ++x) {
      vec4 color1 = texelFetch(tex1, ivec2(x, y), 0);
      vec4 color2 = texelFetch(tex2, ivec2(x, y), 0);
      vec4 diff = color1 - color2;
      len = length(diff);
      if (len > 0.0) break;
    }
    if (len > 0.0) break;
  }
  outColor = mix(vec4(0), vec4(1), step(len, 0.0));
}
`;

// compile shaders, link program, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const textures = canvases.map((canvas) => {
  // gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage, etc.
  return twgl.createTexture(gl, {src: canvas});
});

compareTextures(0, 1);
compareTextures(1, 2);

function compareTextures(ndx1, ndx2) {
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    tex1: textures[ndx1],
    tex2: textures[ndx2],
  });
  
  // draw the bottom right pixel
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
  
  // read the pixel
  const result = new Uint8Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, result);
  
  console.log('textures', ndx1, 'and', ndx2, 'are', result[0] ? 'the same' : 'not the same'); 
}
```

```css
canvas { padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use occlusion queries. The plus is they might not block the GPU where as readPixels does. The minus is you can't check them in the same JavaScript event so they might not fit your needs

```js
// make 3 canvaes as sources for textures
const canvases = ['A', 'B', 'B'].map((msg) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 128;
  canvas.height = 128;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.font = '80px monospace';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fillText(msg, 64, 64);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  return canvas;
});

const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
if (!gl) { alert('need webgl2'); }

const vs = `#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  ivec2 size = textureSize(tex1, 0);  // size of mip 0
  float len = 0.0;
  for (int y = 0; y < size.y; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < size.x; ++x) {
      vec4 color1 = texelFetch(tex1, ivec2(x, y), 0);
      vec4 color2 = texelFetch(tex2, ivec2(x, y), 0);
      vec4 diff = color1 - color2;
      len = length(diff);
      if (len > 0.0) break;
    }
    if (len > 0.0) break;
  }
  if (len > 0.0) {
    discard;
  }
  outColor = vec4(1);
}
`;

// compile shaders, link program, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const textures = canvases.map((canvas) => {
  // gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage, etc.
  return twgl.createTexture(gl, {src: canvas});
});

function wait(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function test() {
  await compareTextures(0, 1);
  await compareTextures(1, 2);
}
test();

async function compareTextures(ndx1, ndx2) {
  gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    tex1: textures[ndx1],
    tex2: textures[ndx2],
  });
  
  // draw the bottom right pixel
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
  
  const query = gl.createQuery();
  gl.beginQuery(gl.ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED, query);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
  gl.endQuery(gl.ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED);
  gl.flush();
  
  let ready = false;
  while(!ready) {
    await wait();
    ready = gl.getQueryParameter(query, gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE);
  }
  
  const same = gl.getQueryParameter(query, gl.QUERY_RESULT);
  
  console.log('textures', ndx1, 'and', ndx2, 'are', same ? 'the same' : 'not the same'); 
}
```

```css
canvas { padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried the two approaches and both work pretty well and fast. Not yet decided which one to keep: 1) Read both textures with gl.readPixels and compare in JavaScript or 2) compare textures in a shader and draw the result in one pixel. I use 512 x 512 gl.RED textures. By the way, I tested gl.readPixels on many texture formats and it doesn't seem to work on RGB textures. I do not need right now RGB textures, but it were nice to have a compare-textures function to use on future projects.

Comment: WebGL2 (OpenGL ES 3.0) only guarantees that you can call `gl.readPixels` with 3 formats/type pairs. `gl.RGBA/gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `gl.RGBA_INTEGER/gl.INT`, `gl.RGBA_INTEGER/gl.UNSIGNED_INT`. So to read a RGB/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture you need to use `gl.RGBA/gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` with readPixels if you want to be portable. An implementation can define one other format/type combination per internalFormat you can use with readPixels which you can query but what format/type combination it returns is implementation specific.

Comment: I reformulated the question and gave more details. Reading both textures with gl.readPixels and comparing them in JavaScript seems to work faster. But even so, this is the more expensive operation and it is slowing too much if it's done at every single iteration.